# how to link ffmpeg libs with android system libs

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am using ffmepg to develope my own functionality for my android system,
I have gotten ffmpeg libs (libavutil.a and so on)  by building ffmpeg project using android NDK
Static libs can be linked by declaring LOCAL_LDFLAGS += lib in Android.mk, however, my ffmpeg libs could not be linked for my project with android system compilation, a vast Error (undefined reference to 'av_xx' )  occurred during compilation process
I  did another test of linking the ffmpeg libs in my project that is NDK compiled, the libs were linked without error 
my own functionality im developing can only be compiled under android source code, how do i fix it, please help

Comment: plz inform me also if you find the answer.

Comment: I think that you need to add those lib's to ndk/sources folder before you can use them